# Connect multiple times to the same wifi network

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, bonding, wlan

Is it possible to connect multiple times (with different MAC addresses) to the same wifi network with just one network card? Is there already a tool to do this?

Comment: Short answer: no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're looking for [mac80211 virtual interface support](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/iw/vif):

> The mac80211 subsystem in the linux kernel supports multiple wireless
>   interfaces to be created with one physical wireless card. This depends
>   on the driver implementing this. This could allow you to join multiple
>   networks at once, or connect to one network while routing traffic from
>   an access point interface.

Answer (score 0):

you are really talking about network virtualization which you could do using applications such as VMware workstation for windows or VMware fusion for MAC users. There are other applications in the market that can be used for similar situation. You will then need to create a virtual OS with multiple vNICs. I personally haven't tried this but in theory it should work.